# rendered attribute called over and over in header (EDIT: h:link vs h:commandLink and session attributes for navigation)

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have a p:poll element in the header of my JSF2 application firing every second to check for the Auction end time (which may change at any moment in the backoffice and I have to stay on top of it.) I'm noticing now that whenever the poll is firing all the "rendered" methods in the header are being called. Why is that? And how can it be stopped?

The part of code that may be relevant for this:

```
<td>Remaining Time: 
    <h:outputText id="remTime" value="#{auctionBean.remainingTime}"/>       
    <p:poll listener="#{auctionBean.calcRemainingTime()}" interval="1" update="remTime" />
</td>
```

EDIT:

A bit more about my functional requirement. I have a home page with eight links: 5 on the header and 3 on the footer. I also have a search component which I need to show -- once the user is logged in -- for 3 of those links. The way I'm doing it is by passing a "fromPage" attribute in the session, and making a decision to show, or hide the search component.

When I am using h:commandLink for all my home page links it all works fine. But another problem arises: the JSF url's are trailing by one click. This is a known issue so I wont' go into detail explaining it.

OK. So I moved to h:link. Now the url's change every click and it behaves normally. But for every click, all the "outcome" methods -- for all 8 links on the home page -- are called from left to write, top to bottom. Yes, all 8 "outcome" methods are called for every click. The url changes correctly and the page is displayed correctly but the "fromPage" attribute in the session is always for the last link called: the one at the bottom right.

To make things even more bizarre, my Search component is always showing, because the last link on the header is for one that it should show for. When I test this by putting another link on the page -- at the top right -- for a page the Search shouldn't show for, the Search now doesn't show ever.

OK. I can simply give up on the url's showing the correct page, switch back to commandLinks, and move on with my life. But I want to get it right, and help my users. Is there a solution?

Comment: Anyone? There is no solution for this issue?

Comment: I edited my question. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use partial processing with process attribute, only process what is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for responding, Catgatay. That's actually what I am trying to do with the p:poll tag: <p:poll listener="#{auctionBean.calcRemainingTime()}" interval="1" update="remTime" /> Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

`h:link` uses what the JSF spec calls "preemptive navigation". From the spec:

> The navigation case is resolved during the 
>   Render Response phase, before the client activates the link (and may never activate the link).

This way, you can use navigation rules just like with `h:commandLink` actions. However, if your outcome is an EL method expression, your "outcome method" as you called it will be called during the render response phase. This is expected behavior.

An alternative that I think might work for you is to add a query parameter to the outcome and put a `f:viewParam` on the target page. For example:

page1.xhtml

```
<h:link value="Page 2" outcome="page2?fromPage=page1"/>
```

page2.xhtml

```
<f:metadata>
    <f:viewParam name="fromPage" value="#{page2.fromPage}"/>
</f:metadata>
```

Now you can use `#{page2.fromPage}` to do your conditional rendering. This probably also avoids having to store `fromPage` in the session.